# No log files produced when java program is run through systemd unit in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, logging, daemon, systemd

OS -> Ubuntu 16.04 x64

When the following java program is run as `<user>` from command line it produces the log files in the directory inside `</home/user>` as configured in the java util logging properties file passed in as system parameter.

```
nohup java -Duser.home=<home/<user>> -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/<user>/<path_to_logging.properties> -cp <jarname>.jar <MainClass> >> /dev/null 2>>/dev/null &
```

However, when the same program is run as the following systemd unit, the program runs okay (can see the the output when it is piped to a file instead of /dev/null) but the log files are not produced!!

```
[Unit]
Description=Daemon Desc

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/<user>/<app>
ExecStart=/usr/share/java -Duser.home=/home/<user> -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/<user>/<path_to_logging.properties> -cp <jarname>.jar <MainClass>

User=<user>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a file permissions issue.  When it runs from systemd, does it run as a user who has permission to both read the logging properties and write to whatever log file the properties specify?

Comment: @VGR I specified to run unit as User=<user> who has the permissions as,  logging.properties -> `-rw-r--r-- <user> <user>` and the log dir -> `drwxrwxr-x <user> <user>`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by calling a shell script that starts the java program rather than calling the java directly from the systemd service. Still not clear why that wouldn't produce any log files.

Comment: I met the same error. I also run the java program through a shell script but it still no log file generated. My log framework is log4j. It works find when I ran the java program through shell scirpt. but it didn't work when it ran as a systemd service. Very weried. Do you have any more understanding about this issue?

Comment: @DoubleQueens did you call the shell script from systemd?